# how i can resolve the error "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error"

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, rest, postman

I am developing the backend part of a registration page for my website, the problem is that when I test this in postman I get the following error:

[image: error in postman]

and I also get this error in my eclipse console:

```
2020-05-29 17:58:06.226 ERROR 1368 --- [nio-8484-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: impossible d'insérer NULL dans ("NAWFEL"."ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR"."IDENTIFIANT")

2020-05-29 17:58:06.230 ERROR 1368 --- [nio-8484-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: impossible d'insérer NULL dans ("NAWFEL"."ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR"."IDENTIFIANT")

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
```

I see that the error comes from the id but as you can see here I inserted the id in postman in the json part :

```
{
    "id":2,
    "EMPLOI":2,
    "ENTITE":2,
    "LOGIN":"hr",
    "MOTDEPASSE":"hr",
    "NOM":"bougrine",
    "PRENOM":"rachid",
    "STATUT":"br",
    "CREEPAR": 2
}
```

this is my code for configure spring security in my app :

```
package com.app.habilitation.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;


@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").
        fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("hr")
        .password("{noop}hr").roles("USER");
    }


}
```

and this is my controller :

```
package com.app.habilitation.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;
import com.app.habilitation.service.UserService;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController (UserService theuserService) {
        userService=theuserService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String login() {
        return "authenticaated succesfully";
    }


    @GetMapping("/getUsers") 
    public String getUsers() {
        return "users";
    }


    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public UserEntity addUser (@RequestBody UserEntity theUser) {

        System.out.println("test");
        userService.save(theUser);

        return theUser;
    }
}
```

and this is my dao ( i use jpa) :

```
package com.app.habilitation.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {



}
```

this is my entity class :

```
package com.app.habilitation.entity;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDO_DEP_UTILISATEUR")
public class UserEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="IDENTIFIANT")
    private Integer IDENTIFIANT;

    /*@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOI") */
    @Column(name="EMPLOI")
    private Integer emploi;

    /* @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="ENTITE") */
    @Column(name="ENTITE")
    private Integer entite;


    @Column(name="LOGIN")
    private String login;


    @Column(name="MOTDEPASSE")
    private String mdp;


    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;

    @Column(name="prenom")
    private String prenom;

    @Column(name="CREEPAR")
    private Integer creerpar;

    @Column(name="ANNULEPAR")
    private Integer annulepar;

    @Column(name="STATUT")
    private String statut;

    @Column(name="DATEEFFET")
    private Date dateeffet;


    @Column(name="DATEFIN")
    private Date datefin;

    @Column(name="CREELE")
    private Date creele;

    @Column(name="MOTIFDEDESACTIVATION")
    private String motifdedesactivation;

    @Column(name="ANNULELE")
    private Date annulele;

    public Integer getIDENTIFIANT() {
        return IDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public void setIDENTIFIANT(Integer iDENTIFIANT) {
        IDENTIFIANT = iDENTIFIANT;
    }

    public Integer getEmploi() {
        return emploi;
    }

    public void setEmploi(Integer emploi) {
        this.emploi = emploi;
    }

    public Integer getEntite() {
        return entite;
    }

    public void setEntite(Integer entite) {
        this.entite = entite;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getMdp() {
        return mdp;
    }

    public void setMdp(String mdp) {
        this.mdp = mdp;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public Integer getCreerpar() {
        return creerpar;
    }

    public void setCreerpar(Integer creerpar) {
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
    }

    public Integer getAnnulepar() {
        return annulepar;
    }

    public void setAnnulepar(Integer annulepar) {
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
    }

    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public Date getDateeffet() {
        return dateeffet;
    }

    public void setDateeffet(Date dateeffet) {
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
    }

    public Date getDatefin() {
        return datefin;
    }

    public void setDatefin(Date datefin) {
        this.datefin = datefin;
    }

    public Date getCreele() {
        return creele;
    }

    public void setCreele(Date creele) {
        this.creele = creele;
    }

    public String getMotifdedesactivation() {
        return motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public void setMotifdedesactivation(String motifdedesactivation) {
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
    }

    public Date getAnnulele() {
        return annulele;
    }

    public void setAnnulele(Date annulele) {
        this.annulele = annulele;
    }

    public UserEntity(Integer iDENTIFIANT, Integer emploi, Integer entite, String login, String mdp, String nom,
            String prenom, Integer creerpar, Integer annulepar, String statut, Date dateeffet, Date datefin,
            Date creele, String motifdedesactivation, Date annulele) {
        IDENTIFIANT = iDENTIFIANT;
        this.emploi = emploi;
        this.entite = entite;
        this.login = login;
        this.mdp = mdp;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.creerpar = creerpar;
        this.annulepar = annulepar;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.dateeffet = dateeffet;
        this.datefin = datefin;
        this.creele = creele;
        this.motifdedesactivation = motifdedesactivation;
        this.annulele = annulele;
    }

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity [IDENTIFIANT=" + IDENTIFIANT + ", emploi=" + emploi + ", entite=" + entite + ", login="
                + login + ", mdp=" + mdp + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", creerpar=" + creerpar
                + ", annulepar=" + annulepar + ", statut=" + statut + ", dateeffet=" + dateeffet + ", datefin="
                + datefin + ", creele=" + creele + ", motifdedesactivation=" + motifdedesactivation + ", annulele="
                + annulele + "]";
    }



}
```

this is my service interface :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;



public interface UserService {




    public void save (UserEntity theUser);


}
```

and this is my service interface Impl :

```
package com.app.habilitation.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.app.habilitation.dao.UserDao;
import com.app.habilitation.entity.UserEntity;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired

    public UserServiceImpl (UserDao theuserDao) {

        userDao = theuserDao;
    }



    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(UserEntity theUser) {

        userDao.save(theUser);

    }



}
```

this is my application.properties ( i change port 8080 to 8484 because a nother application use this port) :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=nawfel       
spring.datasource.password=hr

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8484
```

and this is my table in oracle 10g :

Comment: Q: how i can resolve the error “status”: 500, “error”?  A: Find the problem on the server, and fix it.  Q: How do I fix `ORA-01400: cannot insert null into (string)

Comment: Your setter is wrong. you should do `this.IDENTIFIANT= IDENTIFIANT` not `IDENTIFIANT= IDENTIFIANT` that assigns the value to itself. Your constructor has the same flaw!

Comment: i put this.IDENTIFIANT= IDENTIFIANT but he doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you try GenerationType.auto or sequence. May be oracle 10g doesn't support identity columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are telling in your entity that id is a generated value. Doing so the value is removed by Jpa during insert. You have to change your strategy, if you are supplying the id you should not mark it as autogenerated.
hth